# C Program to write the contents of a directory

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, system-calls, ls

I need to write a simplified version of the ls program in C. It is going to list all of the contents of the current directory. When ran, it should display the same output as this command:

```
ls -alU --time-style=long-iso
```

No arguments are provided to the program. I am having trouble getting started, but I do know I am going to have to make some system calls such as, opendir(), readdir(), lstat(), and getpwuid(). Any help in getting me off the ground and into it is greatly appreciated. I also really want to understand this. Thanks!

Comment: You're asking too early. Read the man pages for those functions, see how to use them and write some code, then come here if you encounter any problem and explain what precisely is the issue you are facing. This question is unfortunately both off topic and too broad.

Comment: *"I am having trouble getting started"*.   I suggest you start with `int main(void) { return 0; }`, since you don't even seem to have that much yet.

Answer (score 2):

Work backward from the output, field by field:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 kaz  kaz       3573 2018-06-07 13:59 .bashrc
```

The name `.bashrc` comes from the `readdir` traversal.

Everything other than the name comes from the `lstat` system call invoked on the name.

The `-rw...` type and flags representation comes from `st_mode` which you have to decode into that form. There are access macros that can help like like `S_ISDIR(mode)` for testing whether it's a directory or `(mode & S_IXUSR) != 0` for testing whether it's executable by the owner.  The `1` is the link count, `st_nlink`. The `kaz` and `kaz` are user and group ID's, converted to text using (for instance) `getpwuid` to obtain a `struct passwd *`, and `getgrgid` to get a `struct group *` which have name fields.  The `3753` is `st_size`.  The date output can be obtained by formatting `st_mtime` using the `strftime` function.

Formatting into padded columns can be done using `printf` or `sprintf`, like: `printf("<%-50s>", "this-is-left-aligned-in-50-col-field")`.

Comment: This is a huge help. I am on the right track now, thanks.